# Intuition behind conditional expected minimum?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I have 4 independent exponential random variables X1, X2, X3, X4 all with mean 1, and I'm trying to find E[min(X1,X2,X3,X4) | X1>X2>X3>X4]. I found the answer to be 1/4 after a ton of math, but I still don't understand intuitively why 1/4 is the answer. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: The condition seems to be redundant... Why not $\mathrm{E}[\min(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)]$ or $\mathrm{E}[X_4 | X_1>X_2>X_3>X_4]$?

Comment: Hint: characterize the exponential as the waiting time for a homogeneous Poisson process.  Consider four independent processes: the minimum is the waiting time to the first event of those four.